# Table Rows or Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a project which requires me to setup custom privileges, divided in three categories "Admin, Manager, User" 
My regular approach is to distribute Privileges in one table as headers, then add a raw for each category with 0 or 1 to activate or deactivate the privilege for a group like follows:

```
id|name|can_do_this|can_do_that
1|admin|1|1
2|manager|1|0
3|user|0|0
```

however my professor requested that each privilege to be added separately per user no per group like follows:

```
id|user_id|privilege|active
1,1,can_do_this,1
2,1,can_do_that,1
3,2,can_do_this,1
4,2,can_do_that,0
```

my question, for the sake of my sanity.. which is more efficient? his point is that IF we needed to add a new privilege we won't need to ALTER the table to add a new column. 
hope this question makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To me, this is a very simple data modeling issue.  You have two "entities" in your data model:

- users
- privileges

This suggests that each one should have its own table.

Because this is a many-to-many relationship (many users can have a given privilege, one user can have many privileges), a third table is normally used for expressing the relationship; this is often called a "junction table" or "association table".

Your professor gives one very good reason for expressing the values in rows rather than columns:  The ability to add new privileges.

I can add a few more:

- The `userPrivileges` table can have a `createdOn` column so you know when the privilege took effect.
- The `userPrivileges` can have a `createdBy` column, so you know who granted the privilege.
- The `userPrivileges` table can have a `suspended` column, so you can temporarily suspend privileges.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but doesn't that add to the data size? let's say you have a website with 1 million users, and you have like 20 privileges, that would consume a load of MBs.

Comment: in addition, imaging that you should add another privilege, doesn't that mean you need to add 1 million lines to the table?

Comment: @TarekSawah denormalized table structures like the one you had are more likly to consume more disk space then a normalized table structure because of the repeating values for example admin, manager, user .. That requires more bytes in storage then repeating a  integer (4 bytes) (category_id) when using a normalized approach

Comment: @TarekSawah . . . I wouldn't worry about the data size for 1 million users and 20 privileges.  You are talking about at most hundreds of megabytes of storage -- which is tiny.  As for speedy access, indexes are what you would want anyway.

Comment: @TarekSawah . . . A new privilege row only needs to be added for users who have the privilege, not for all users.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you the second one, because like that as your teacher says you don't need to Alter the table. Altering the table would mean adding a new 1 or 0 for each member in your table (you could use a default value but you will still need to change the values for those users that need the privilege).

The way your teachers says you could have another table with all the privileges, and use a foreign key.

That way you could add a new privilege and asign it to the users they need it with a default value of "1", and if you need to revoke the privilege change it for a "0". No innecesari rows will be added for default, that in small tables is not a problem but for bigger ones it is.

```
id  |user_id   |privilege   |active
1      1        can_do_this    1
2      1        can_do_that    1
3      2        can_do_this    1
4      2        can_do_that    0
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, If you don't want to add the extra column every time whenever a new privilege required to be updated in apps. Then go with second option.

Benefit:
Option-1: There will be no redundant data for group and that can be managed easily as you can apply the unique constraint on the group name and hence it will not requires the insert every time.

Option-2: You don't need to add the alter the table you can simply verify does new permission is already there or not, if not then simply add a new insert or update the existing permission.

Dis-advantage:
Option-1: You need to alter the table every time whenever new permission comes in.

Option-2: Whenever you want to add the new permission for a group first you have to identify that the records already exists or not, then you have to insert into table. And while validating the is also a bit of complex compare to the first option.

So, both has its advantage and disadvantages. If you think from data redundant perspective then go with option-1, else go with option-2.

I would prefer to go with option-1 as per my knowledge, and what I will do I just maintain a extra table which identify the permission and physical column between them, and I will make it generic.

ThatsAll!!!

Comment: "Whenever you want to add the new permission for a group first you have to identify that the records already exists or not, then you have to insert into table. " Unique key (group_id, privilege_id) solves that "problem"